# Stepper motor shield compatibilty question

Tags: arduino-mega, stepper

I recently bought Adafruit's motor shield v2 only to find out it can only support upto 12v.

So I'm on the look out for another shield & found this one 
[Arduino Dual L6470 Stepper Motor Shield](http://altelectronics.co.uk/shop/arduino/arduino-stepper-motor-shield/prod_84.html)

I have an Arduino Mega & the documentation says it is fully compatible with the UNO.

Will there an issue using this shield with a Mega? Or if anyone else can point me at a decent stepper controller?

Answer (score 1):

That is an SPI based device, and it doesn't use the (now considered standard) 6-pin ICSP header for SPI.

Therefore it will only directly work on boards that have the SPI pins available on pins 10-13 of the digital headers.

To use it with other boards you will need to manually route the SPI pins to the right places using wires.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, the L6470 is a pretty sophisticated and high-performance driver with lots of options to tweak, but it is a voltage-mode driver that requires some tuning for best results (otherwise, expect to generate some heat). There is a separate ST microelectronics application note, not mentioned in the L6470 datasheet, that describes some tuning guidelines - but it's written for an engineering audience.

There is also a SparkFun version of the L6470 out there.